# Sublime Text 2 project default file(s) for building

Tags: settings, sublimetext2

I am a beginner user of Sublime Text 2, but I was trying to set up project specific default file(s) to build from. I'll explain myself:

When writing in LaTeX, I tend to separate the sections or chapters in different .tex files. When I build, I would like the main file to be the one passed to the compiler no matter what file has focus (a section/chapter .tex or the .log file or any other file for that matter).

Similarly, when writing C++ code, I would like to be able to specify a list of files to pass to the compiler.

Right now I am using a copy of the C++ build-system with `*.cpp` instead of the current file in the `"cmd"` line, but not always I want to build every cpp file in the folder. A similar modification on the LaTeX builder would be possible changing the file to build to something like `main.tex` and using **main.tex** for the main file every time.

Even though these are workarounds, I was wondering if there was a way of defining the default file(s) to the be passed to the compiler (or to a batch file if necessary) from the project specific files.

Comment: You may want to use a Makefile instead.

Comment: @Blender Thanks for pointing me in the right track.
For those who, like me, haven't used make before, I ended up using make from MinGW, and changing the build system to makefile. I learn about makefiles by googling makefile tutorial